# Next js doesn't run with SWC plugin / rust plugin

Tags: rust, next.js, swc-compiler

I create the first plugin exactly like in the documentation - https://swc.rs/docs/plugin/ecmascript/getting-started

I didn't change anything after: swc plugin new --target-type wasm32-wasi my-first-plugin.

Plugin does nothing.

add to Next js:

```
const nextConfig = {
  experimental: {
    appDir: true,
    swcPlugins: [
        [require.resolve("./my_first_plugin.wasm"),{}]
    ],
  },
}
```

Start the server - npm run dev

I see in the console:

```
ready - started server on 0.0.0.0:3000, url: http://localhost:3000
warn  - You have enabled experimental features (appDir, swcPlugins) in next.config.js.
info  - Thank you for testing `appDir` please leave your feedback at https://nextjs.link/app-feedback
warn  - Experimental features are not covered by semver, and may cause unexpected or broken application behavior. Use at your own risk.
```

And the server immediately stops. No errors

The plugin builds without errors.

Tried two builds:

1. wasm32-wasi
2. wasm32-unknown-unknown

**I am using the latest versions of rust, cargo, next js**